# Endless php warning loop on attempt to run php script in Linux shell

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, amazon-web-services

I need to install a freeware php product on AWS. Im given a directory and basically all I need to do is run a command:

`$ php bin/install`

However whenever I attempt to do it, I encounter an endless loop of php warnings:

```
PHP Warning:  fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /vendor/symfony/console/Helper/QuestionHelper.php on line 243
PHP Warning:  feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /vendor/symfony/console/Helper/QuestionHelper.php on line 242
```

It goes on forever until I force stop it. The part of code that is causing the issue:

```
241:  // Read a keypress
242:        while (!feof($inputStream)) {
243:            $c = fread($inputStream, 1);
```

Its obviously a while loop, that occurs because for some reason the script cannot get a keyboard input during setup process.

I have tested it on other hosting, with the same PHP 7.1 version and it all went smoothly. Therefore the issue is in server itself rather than the script.

Is there something basic that I'm missing here?

Comment: Even though it's probably a configuration issue it helps knowing what part of the code is causing the issue.

Comment: @apokryfos Sorry, I have edited the question and added the code.

Comment: Yes but the problem is that `$inputStream` is not a resource in AWS so also add the initialisation code for it.

Comment: @apokryfos Thank you! I am pretty clueless about linux, could you please point me to a specific tutorial?

Comment: Just link to the product you're trying to install. If you need a PHP tutorial then googling for one can't hurt.

Comment: @apokryfos its [shlink](https://shlink.io/installation) The install run perfectly on other server though.

Comment: I'd suggest going through the projects requirements and checking if they are installed (running php -m will tell you what modules are installed on PHP) You need at least curl, intl and a few more.

Comment: I have compared the modules on both servers and I'm missing the following: gmp, intl, ldap, modperf_ext, shmop, soap, tidy. Are there any other modules that should be installed at once?

Comment: You should ask the provider of the installer what its dependencies are, and provide feedback that their script doesn't properly check that the necessary dependencies are installed before proceeding. There's no general answer to which modules you might need to install.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bug report for an (unnamed) third party project.